# Update on duplicate using javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I got two object arrays to compare and return a result which contains two arrays one for insert and one for update.

- aObj --> parent object. (primary/unique key is empid)
- bObj --> children object.(primary/unique key is empid)

```js
let a = [
  { empid: "emp001", name: "test1", status: "emp" },
  { empid: "emp002", name: "test2", status: "ex-emp" },
  { empid: "emp003", name: "test3", status: "emp" }
];

let b = [
  { empid: "emp001", name: "test1_updated", status: "emp" },
  { empid: "emp002", name: "test2", status: "emp" }
];

//insert array
// console.log(_.differenceBy(a, b, 'empid'));

//update array
let updateArr = [],
  insertArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  let aObj = a[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
    let bObj = b[j];
    if (aObj.empid === bObj.empid) {
      if (aObj.status !== bObj.status || aObj.name !== bObj.name) {
        updateArr.push(aObj);
      }
    } else {
      insertArr.push(aObj);
    }
  }
}
console.log("--update--");
console.log(updateArr);
console.log("--insert--");
console.log(insertArr);
```

Code Links - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-kare-ixht9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.differenceBy()` by `empid` to get the insert array, and `_.intersectionWith()` to find items with the same `empid` that are not equal.

```js
const a = [
  { empid: "emp001", name: "test1", status: "emp" },
  { empid: "emp002", name: "test2", status: "ex-emp" },
  { empid: "emp003", name: "test3", status: "emp" }
];

const b = [
  { empid: "emp001", name: "test1_updated", status: "emp" },
  { empid: "emp002", name: "test2", status: "ex-emp" } // equals to emp002
];

const updateArr = _.intersectionWith(a, b, (a, b) => a.empid === b.empid && !_.isEqual(a, b));
const insertArr = _.differenceBy(a, b, 'empid');

console.log("--update--");
console.log(updateArr); // emp001
console.log("--insert--");
console.log(insertArr); // emp003
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @OriDrori --> How to ignore the duplicate objects? 

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-kare-ixht9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark


empid: 'emp004' should not be either inserted or updated. Bcoz it has not change.

Comment: @OriDrori --> what is the equivalent version for this answer in JavaScript or ES6? Was trying to understand compare on 2 loops and splice if found?

Comment: You can create intersectionBy and differenceBy by reducing an array to a Map, and then filtering the other using the Map. intersectionWith requires filter with some, because you need to check the items against each other.